# Where to download a specific version of tensorflow.js without a CDN

Tags: download, tensorflow.js

I am in the process of publishing a Firefox extension that includes a copy of the minified tensorflow.js library. In Mozilla's [Third Party Library Usage guidelines](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/third-party-library-usage/), the following is stated:

> You should download third-party libraries from their official site, not from a CDN or other location. This point is important.

It therefore seems that I am not allowed to use the [download URL](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/tf.min.js.) I see being used in every tf.js project, since it serves the library through a CDN.

I have been looking through the Tensorflow.js [repository at Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs), trying to find a "releases" directory or similar from where to download a specific version of tf.min.js, but I have been unable to find anything like that.

Where could I find an official, stable direct download link to a given version of tf.min.js which is not served by a CDN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not find the `tf.min.js` file in the GitHub repo because TensorFlow.js is written in TypeScript. The JavaScript files are only generated at build time and not committed to the repo.

The [official TensorFlow.js website](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup) does not offer direct downloads but does offer a second option in addition to using a CDN: you can download any given release of TensorFlow.js via npm.

The main package in npm is [@tensorflow/tfjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs). You can install in a project in the usual way with `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs`, or alternatively if you just want a full copy of the package source without using the `node_modules` directory, you can run the following:

```
npm pack @tensorflow/tfjs
```

This will give you a tarball file like `tensorflow-tfjs-1.7.0.tgz`. You can unpack this with:

```
tar -xf tensorflow-tfjs-1.7.0.tgz
```

Now you'll find `tf.min.js` within `package/dist`. You'll also find a non-minified `tf.js`.

As it happens, the `tf.min.js` file is precisely the same as the one on the CDN (the hashes match). However, using an npm release does provide a reliable method for fetching a precise version from an official source, so these instructions may better satisfy the review process.